# Validation of ViewModel throws exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, viewmodel

I have a viewmodel that contains a product and SelectList of categories.

```
public class AdFormViewModel
{
    public AmericanAds.Model.Ad Ad { get; set; }
    public SelectList Categories { get; set; }

    public AdFormViewModel(AmericanAds.Model.Ad ad, SelectList categories)
    {
        Ad = ad;
        Categories = categories;
    }
}
```

When adding a new product, if validation fails for category dropdown I get below error message.

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'AmericanAds.Model.Ad' but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'AmericanAds.Controllers.AdFormViewModel'.

Here is the controller for create action.

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        AdFormViewModel data = new AdFormViewModel(
            null,
            new SelectList(_repository.CategoryList().ToList(), "CategoryId", "CategoryName")
            );

        return View(data);
    } 

    //
    // POST: /Ad/Create

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create(Ad ad)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _repository.AddAd(ad);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View(ad);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return View(ad);
        }
    }
```

What am I missing?

As you can tell, I am very new to ASP.Net MVC.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this asp.net-mvc 2?  Otherwise, which validation engine are you running?  Can you show us some view markup and the action where this fails?

Comment: it is mvc 1.0. I will add some code to the post

Comment: Out of curiosity, how can validation fail for a dropdown in this scenario?  Does it sometimes work and sometimes fail?  If so, what are the inputs each time?  Does it always fail?  If so on what line?

Comment: In the View the dropdown is defined like
<%= Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", Model.Categories, "Please select") %> 
so if user does not select a value and leave it as "Please select" then the validation fails. 
As Cagdas picked up, problem wasnt validation related, I wasnt returning ViewModel object when model state is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `Create` view requires a model of type `AdFormViewModel` but in your `Create` action (the one with the `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` attribute) you return a model of type `Ad` (see the lines where it says `return View(ad)`).

Like the exception message says ; It requires an `AmericanAds.Controllers.AdFormViewModel` but you are sending an `AmericanAds.Model.Ad`.

And no, I don't think this has anything to do with the validation.